# not getting data using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I have an application (say A1), which fetches data from another application (say A2) using API.

A2 returns data in PHP's **serialized** format. Any application can access this data using a URL and query-string (which also contains authentication code)

```
http://example-a2.com/index.php?process=get_results&time=today&auth_code=123456
```

which returns data as (data is not complete, but just want to show that it returns data in serialize manner, when I type above URL in browser)

```
a:425:{s:10:"2010-02-19";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-02-20";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-02-21";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-02-22";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-02-23";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-02-24";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-02-25";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-02-26";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-02-27";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-02-28";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-01";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-02";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-03";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-04";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-05";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-06";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-07";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-08";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-09";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-10";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-11";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-12";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-13";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-14";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-15";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-16";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-17";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-18";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-19";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-20";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-21";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-22";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-23";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-24";a:0:{}s:10:"2010-03-25";a:0:{}s:10:"2
```

Now, problem is that I am not able to fetch serialized data using cURL in application **A1**.

I am using following code

```
$url = 'http://example-a2.com/index.php?process=get_results&time=today&auth_code=123456';
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

if (empty($buffer))
{
    print 'sorry';
}
else
{
    var_dump($buffer);
}
```

and I get following output

```
string(165) " "
```

Can someone point me out what's wrong with the code?

Comment: I assume the URL mismatch is a typo when pasting code here :-?

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: I was editing that one, it was typo. Sorry.

Comment: I see nothing intrinsically wrong in your code. Does your app require cookies or issue HTTP redirections?

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: No app does not require any cookie (I have checked it with Private Browsing in Firefox). It also does not issue any form of redirections

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: Process is quite simple. I can copy paste URL in browser, and it shows data in serialized PHP format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not inspecting the real output:

```
string(165) " "
```

`var_dump()` says you have a string of 165 bytes but only a white space is shown. If you are displaying it through a browser, make sure you send a `Content-Type: text/plain` header or use the View Source feature.

Comment: I use the 'View Source' feature, but it's not showing me any data, it's just empty spaces.

Comment: You can add a debug line to A1 that saves into a file the same input that's sent to the client, so you can compare.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of doing that only.